# Mesh is not moving with bone even with correct weights

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

The bones are moving outside the mesh during deformation. I have manually painted each bone in the leg, yet the mesh still does not conform to the bones. Also, I did paint the underside of the foot.

[image]

Comment: there must be another bone influencing this part of your mesh, in edit mode, select it, go in the Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups, on the right of this list click on the down arrow to open the menu, choose Remove From All Groups, then switch back to Weight Paint mode and repaint this part

Answer (score 0):

I would use automatic weights, and verify that the mesh is moving with the bones and then manipulate the automatic weights with your weight painting. I'm a novice though.